# How to running XCUItest in Firebase testlab via fastlane?

Tags: swift, fastlane, firebase-test-lab

Using testlab in firebase, I want ui tests to be tested automatically. To integrate this process into the CI/CD process, I added the lane below to my fastfile. But I get the error "Could not find action, lane or variable 'firebase_test_lab_ios_xctest". What could be the cause of the error?

```
desc "Firebase Test"
   lane :test do |options|
     scan(
       clean: true,
       skip_detect_devices: true,
       build_for_testing: true,
       sdk: 'iphoneos',
       should_zip_build_products: true
     )
    
     firebase_test_lab_ios_xctest(
       gcp_project: 'xxxx-24b103', #Google Cloud project name
       devices: [
         {
           ios_model_id: 'iphone11',
           ios_version_id: '14.5',
           locale: 'en_US',
           orientation: 'portrait'
         }
        ]
      )
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to install `fastlane-plugin-firebase_test_lab` first. Run [this command](https://rubygems.org/gems/fastlane-plugin-firebase_test_lab/versions/1.0.7):

```
gem install fastlane-plugin-firebase_test_lab
```

Comment: I added it, but I keep getting the same error. Could there be a deficiency or error in the lane I wrote?